# Unable to generate SpecFlow LivingDoc

Tags: specflow

I've followed the steps provided in the SpecFlow livingdoc documentation however when i try to generate LivingDoc, i'm hitting error.

1. Installed SpecFlow.Plus.LivingDoc.CLI

   - Tool 'specflow.plus.livingdoc.cli' is already installed.
2. Navigated to folder where .dll and .json file is located

   Test_Project.dll and TestExecution.json is located here.
3. Executed "livingdoc test-assembly Test_Project.dll -t TestExecution.json"

Error message

```
Unhandled exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex cannot be larger than length of string. (Parameter 'startIndex')
at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex)
at LivingDoc.CLI.Parser.TestAssemblyFeatureFileProvider.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<GetFeatureFileResources>b__1(String fn) in D:\a\1\s\src\SpecFlow.Integration\LivingDoc.CLI\Parser\TestAssemblyFeatureFileProvider.cs:line 27
at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectListIterator`2.ToList()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at LivingDoc.CLI.Parser.TestAssemblyFeatureFileProvider.GetFeatureFileResources() in D:\a\1\s\src\SpecFlow.Integration\LivingDoc.CLI\Parser\TestAssemblyFeatureFileProvider.cs:line 25
at LivingDoc.CLI.Parser.Parser.Parse(String rootNodeTitle, String projectLanguage, String workItemPrefix, String workItemUrlTemplate) in D:\a\1\s\src\SpecFlow.Integration\LivingDoc.CLI\Parser\Parser.cs:line 33
at LivingDoc.CLI.ReportGenerator.Generate(GeneratorSource source, Parameters parameters) in D:\a\1\s\src\SpecFlow.Integration\LivingDoc.CLI\ReportGenerator.cs:line 73
at LivingDoc.CLI.ArgumentResolver.Handle(String workingFolder, GeneratorSource source, Parameters parameters) in D:\a\1\s\src\SpecFlow.Integration\LivingDoc.CLI\ArgumentResolver.cs:line 214
at LivingDoc.CLI.ArgumentResolver.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Resolve>b__0(Parameters p) in D:\a\1\s\src\SpecFlow.Integration\LivingDoc.CLI\ArgumentResolver.cs:line 161
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
at System.CommandLine.Invocation.ModelBindingCommandHandler.InvokeAsync(InvocationContext context)
at System.CommandLine.Invocation.InvocationPipeline.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<<BuildInvocationChain>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c.<<UseParseErrorReporting>b__21_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<<UseHelp>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass25_0.<<UseVersionOption>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<<UseTypoCorrections>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c.<<UseSuggestDirective>b__22_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c.<<UseParseDirective>b__20_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c.<<UseDebugDirective>b__11_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c.<<RegisterWithDotnetSuggest>b__10_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<<UseExceptionHandler>b__0>d.MoveNext()
```

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Reason behind this issue was, you had set the Platform target version to x86/x64, So the assembly not able to support.

Solution :
Change Platform version to Any CPU => Refer the screenshot for the same.

[image]